# ATI HD 5970 display

Tags: graphics-card

Hello everyone i'm a little worry about my graphic card. before I get into that I will tell you my system specs. I have intel dx58so mainboard, 6gb corsair xms ddr3 ram, intel i7 960 cpu, and ati hd 5970. I'm also using a coolmaster haf92 case. My OS is vista X64. 
Here is my issue when I type in dxdiag in (Start Search) and I look into display. I see in (approx total memory) 716mb graphic memory. The ati hd 5970 is a 2gb graphic card. Am I being stuipd or is there an issue.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://forums.legitreviews.com/about29566.html

Answer (score 1):

Its not related to the actual physical ram on the gpu, I have a 512mb 4870 and its read as 2296mb in dxdiag, you don't have to bother yourself if the performance is not hindered in anyway
you can also download gpuz
http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/SysInfo/GPU-Z/ 
and check for the specs it might give you a more straight forward accurate reading.